# seleccionar el nombre de una columna que se encuentra en una variable tipo VARCHAR TSQL

Tags: tsql, transact-sql

junto con saludar a la comunidad tengo una duda con el siguiente codigo

```
DECLARE @N_COLUMNA VARCHAR (MAX)
            SET @N_COLUMNA = 'UNO'
            SELECT COUNT (0) FROM  VW_ESCRITURA WHERE @N_COLUMNA  LIKE   '%ROBERTO ORLANDO%'
```

mi pregunta es, ¿como puedo llamar al nombre de columna de una tabla que contengo en una variable? como en el ejemplo de arriba.

Ejemplo de tabla VW_ESCRITURA
[image: Ejemplo de tabla VW_ESCRITURA]

EDITADO Según respuesta

El código finalmente quedo así pero sigo teniendo un problema con las variables, el @count siempre queda en 0 siendo que deberia de marcar en 1 cuando encuentre el nombre en la columna correspondiente
`

```
> DECLARE @count as INT
  DECLARE @CAV_NOMBRE_PROPIETARIO VARCHAR(MAX)
    SELECT @CAV_NOMBRE_PROPIETARIO = [CAV_NOMBRE_PROPIETARIO] FROM TCG_DOCUMENTOS  WHERE WORKITEM =  CAST (@WorkItem AS varchar) AND DOCINDEX = CAST (@DocIndex AS VARCHAR)             
  DECLARE @query nvarchar(max) = 'SELECT @count = COUNT(0) FROM VW_ESCRITURA WHERE ' + @N_Columna + ' LIKE @ParamValor' 
    EXEC sp_executesql  @query,N'@paramValor NVARCHAR(MAX), @count INT OUTPUT',@ParamValor= @CAV_NOMBRE_PROPIETARIO , @count=@count OUTPUT; 
print @count`
```

a diferencia del código de la respuesta que si me devolvía un valor 1 cuando encontraba el nombre en dicha columna.
Espero se entienda

Comment: Si esa es la respuesta, añádela como respuesta, no en la pregunta. Después puedes incluso marcarla como aceptada

Answer (score 1):

Puedes armar el query en un string y ejecutarlo con **sp_executesql**, como en el siguiente ejemplo

```
DECLARE @N_COLUMNA VARCHAR (MAX) = 'UNO'
DECLARE @valor NVARCHAR(MAX) = '%ROBERTO ORLANDO%'
DECLARE @query nvarchar(max) = 'SELECT COUNT(0) FROM vwProductos WHERE ' + @N_Columna + ' LIKE @ParamValor'
EXEC sp_executesql  @query, N'@paramValor NVARCHAR(MAX)',@ParamValor= @valor
```

Observa que los parámetros que uses en el query se deben de declarar y asignar el valor en la instrucción sp_executesql, revisa la documentación en la siguiente página:
[sp_executesql (Transact-SQL)](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-Es/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: gracias por tu comentario , me sirvió mucho y ha sido de mucha ayuda  aunque de cierta manera tuve problemas al agregarle las variables con las que estaba trabajando.

Comment: Un gusto poderte ayudar, si necesitas ayuda con las variables házmelo saber.